# Where to put gem configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using stw_engine gem to get screenshots of websites. This gem requires to provide own config, but I don't know where it should be put. It gives an error `StwEngine error: No api secret defined!` if I put it to `initializers/stw.rb`

```
StwEngine.config({

    # required
    :api_key      => 'xXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    :private_key  => 'xxxx,

    #optional use if supported
    :size  => 'lg',


})
```

gem page:
https://github.com/sabirmostofa/stw-engin

Comment: Are you putting actual values for :api_key? And did you add this to your routes? `mount StwEngine::Engine => "/stw_engine"`

Comment: Yes, I did both of them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code to `initializers/stw_engine.rb`. Also, there must be `:api_secret => 'xxxxx'` instead `:private_key`